# Why are indirect assembly dependencies sometimes required and sometimes not in .NET projects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Here's an age-old question that I'm ashamed to ask, as I should know the answer after 15+ years of .NET development:

I'll often have an application project A which has a reference to class library project B, which itself depends on assembly C.

Sometimes it's enough for me to reference  project B from A, build and run the application and everything works fine.  This is the behavior I'd expect, as B's dependencies should be handled by B.

But other times, when I run application A, I get errors complaining that it "could not load file or assembly C."

As a concrete example, I have a WPF application which is dependent on a .NET Standard project which has a Nuget dependency of Entity Framework Core 2.2.  To resolve the issue, I need to add a Nuget reference from my WPF application directly, which doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Why is this?

Comment: if the reference dll exists in the bin of the B projects and B is reference by A then the published executable bin normally have dll of B and it's dependent dlls i guess

Comment: It is not a 15+ year problem.  Somewhere around version 4.5 the C# compiler got more demanding about it.  Probably due to a bug report.  Happens when the assembly reference exposes a type of another assembly in method overloads.  Today the C# compiler demands to know such a type so it can pick the correct overload, previously it was happy with not knowing it.  Overload resolution is certainly one of the most convoluted problems it has to solve, the language specification doesn't dictate what must happen in the "unknown type" case.  Many questions about it, none that makes anybody happy.

Comment: @HansPassant So my GUI application, for example, will need to add references to all the Nuget packages, etc. that all the referenced projects depend on?  That seems redundant; I thought adding project references would take care of the dependency tree.

Comment: File a bug with the library owner to get this resolved.  Be sure to do a better job than you did here, he needs to know the exact error message and a code snippet.

Comment: I wasn't aware that this was even a bug with the library owner, but that's good to know.  This is an issue that happens frequently when I include references to other projects I've written, which reference, for example, EntityFrameworkCore.  For some reason my main application will have to reference EntityFrameworkCore *as well as* the project I'm referencing.  I can try to do a better job of providing a specific example, and you can do a better job answering with an answer and not a comment.